# Pessoa Física e Jurídica na mesma tabela

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Poderiam me ajudar por favor ?

Estou desenvolvendo um crud para cliente, aonde irei deixar pessoa física e jurídica na mesma tabela, mas no caso quando o usuário escolher o tipo de pessoa através de um radio button, irei mostrar e esconder alguns campos através de javascript, e os únicos campos que serão obrigatórios serão:

Pessoa Física: Nome

Pessoa Jurídica: Razão Social.

Como a estrutura faz parte do mesmo formulário, e os campos nome e razaoSocial são obrigátorios, preciso preencher os dois campos independente de o cliente ser físico ou jurídico, então gostaria de saber como posso contornar esse problema.

AddClientViewModels:

```
 public class ApplicationClient
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Tipo Pessoa")]
    public int TipoPessoa { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nome é obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "O {0} deve ter pelo menos {2} e no máximo {1} caracteres.", MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Display(Name = "Nome")]
    public String Nome { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Razão Social é obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "A {0} deve ter pelo menos {2} e no máximo {1} caracteres.", MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Display(Name = "Razão Social")]
    public String RazaoSocial { get; set; }
 }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Add(AddClientViewModels model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

            if (user == null)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException($"Não é possível carregar o usuário com o ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
            }

            var client = new ApplicationClient { TipoPessoa = model.TypePerson,Nome = model.Name,
                                                 RazaoSocial = model.CompanyName
            };

            var result = await _clientManager.CreateClientAsync(client);

            TempData["MensagemSucesso"] = "Cliente cadastrado com sucesso";

            return View("Index");
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: você quer manter o *required*, mas quer que valide conforme seja pessoa física ou jurídica, é isso?

Comment: Exatamente Ricardo, mas como os dois campos são _required_ me obrigado a preencher os dois campos para poder enviar o formulário.

Comment: Seria bom vc postar o `AddClientViewModels` para vermos a estrutura. Outro ponto é que não faz sentido vc manter os `Required` quando de fato, não são.

Comment: Se quiser manter o *required*, precisa escrever uma classe para validar a Model, verificando se é física ou jurídica. Isso é feito implementado a interface `IValidatableObject`, que na verdade é bem simples

Comment: Fernando obrigado pela resposta, é que no caso, se o cliente for Físico o `Nome` é _required_, caso ele seja Jurídico a `RazaoSocial` é _required_, já arrumei a pergunta conforme a solicitação.

Comment: Você pode criar as 2 entidades PessoaFisica e PessoaJuridica mapeando o EntityFramework para a mesma tabela cada uma com as suas respectivas propriedades. No momento do post dos dados você escolhe para qual action vai enviar os dados de acordo com o radio button.

Comment: Ricardo Potual, se possível conseguiria me dar um exemplo ?

Comment: Sim, coloquei um exemplo pra você entender como funciona.

Comment: Ricardo sua resposta foi Perfeita

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aqui um exemplo de como pode alterar sua model e implementar o método `Validate`:

```
// adicione a interface IValidatableObject
public class ApplicationClient: IValidatableObject
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Tipo Pessoa")]
    public int TipoPessoa { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "O {0} deve ter pelo menos {2} e no máximo {1} caracteres.", MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Display(Name = "Nome")]
    public String Nome { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "A {0} deve ter pelo menos {2} e no máximo {1} caracteres.", MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Display(Name = "Razão Social")]
    public String RazaoSocial { get; set; }

    // implemente o método Validate
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (TipoPessoa == 1 && String.IsNullOrEmpty(Nome)) // supondo física
            yield return new ValidationResult("Nome é obrigatório", new [] { nameof(Nome) });

        if (TipoPessoa == 2 && String.IsNullOrEmpty(RazaoSocial)) // supondo jurídica
            yield return new ValidationResult("Razão Social é obrigatório", new [] { nameof(RazaoSocial) });
    }
}
```

Ao usar `yield return` você está retornando um erro de validação para sua Model, que será exibido no html